# ¿Como insertar una imagen png en pdf?

Tags: python, imagen, pdf, reportlab

Cuando ingreso una imagen de esta manera:

```
c.drawImage('prueba.png', 25, 480, 480, 270)
```

me genera el siguiente error:

> Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs

¿Como puedo insertar esa imagen en Reportlab?

Comment: Prueba a instalar [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) si no lo tienes: en el mismo intérprete/entorno virtual `python -m pip install pillow`.

Comment: ya esta en la versión mas reciente